# Refresh JMS Connection in Spring Project using ActiveMQ

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I have a Spring project in which I am using Apache Camel and ActiveMQ as message broker. When I started my Java application which receives from the topic and when the broker is not started it gives an error (which is valid), but even after starting the broker JMS connection is not refreshed.

I tried the same case in the Spring Boot app and it automatically refreshed the JMS connection. Something needs to be handled manually in Spring but not sure of that thing.

This is the error from my Spring app:

```
org.apache.camel.component.jms.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer: Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'test.events.topic' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=1, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://activemq:61616. Reason: java.net.UnknownHostException: activemq
```

This is what the Spring Boot application reports:

```
Successfully refreshed JMS Connection
```

Below is the broker configuration:

```
broker:
    host: localhost
    port: 61616
    protocol: tcp
    endpoint: ${broker.protocol}://${broker.host}:${broker.port}
    url: failover:(${broker.endpoint}?wireFormat.maxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=30000)?timeout=3000&jms.useCompression=true&startupMaxReconnectAttempts=0&jms.redeliveryPolicy.maximumRedeliveries=${maxConsumers}
```

Comment: The output from `DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer` indicates that it will retry to establish the connection after `5000` milliseconds and that it will keep retrying indefinitely. Do you see additional retries after the initial failed attempt?

Comment: Yes @JustinBertram, even when broker is started these logs are getting printed indefinitely and application is not connected to broker

Comment: If you continue to receive `java.net.UnknownHostException` after the broker is up that indicates that the result of the DNS lookup is being cached somewhere. This may be an environmental issue to prevent excessive requests to the DNS server.